# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<TimerState> above this Practice4HomePage Widget Flutter(BLoc)

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

I got an error when learning bloc in flutter

Error is
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Practice4HomePage Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Practice4HomePage is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
     child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide the bloc to your `Practice4HomePage` class. One way is to provide the bloc to the entire widget tree i.e. wrapping `MaterialApp` with `BlocProvider` or `MultiBlocProvider`. Another way is to wrap `BlocProvider` which you are calling `Practice4HomePage`. So let's suppose you are navigating from the ABC page to `Practice4HomePage`, you can wrap `BlocProvider` inside your navigation statement.

Example:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute<HomeForm>(
    builder: (context) => BlocProvider<TimerState>(
      create: (context) => TimerState(),
      child: Practice4HomePage(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to use BlocProvider instead of Provider, and secondly, wrap your child widget with Builder because BlocProvider.of(context) (or in this case context.watch()) looks from current context up the tree to find your BlocProvider, and you use same context that you provided your Bloc with, so it can't find it up the tree because it's on the same level (same context), so just use suggestion that was provided by your error, or like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocProvider<Example>(
    create: (_) => Example(),
    child: Builder(builder: (context) => Text(context.watch<Example>())),
  ),
}
```

Or you can extract Text widget into a new StatelessWidget and that will also work because it will have it's own (new) BuildContext, like so:

```
class ParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      child: ChildWidget(),
    ),
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(context.watch<Example>());
  }
}
```