# Flutter how can i use cubit context watch?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I trying learn cubit but i always having same error while i try check a variable from cubit.

**My error is like :**

[image]

I made a BlocProvider and inside i put my Cubit. Like:

```
BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => LoginCubit(
          _formKey, emailController, passwordController,
          service: LoginService(Dio())),
      child: Scaffold(...
```

**My LoginCubit:**

```
class LoginCubit extends Cubit<LoginState> {
  final TextEditingController emailController;
  final TextEditingController passwordController;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey;
  final ILoginService service;
  bool isLoading = false;
  LoginCubit(this.formKey, this.emailController, this.passwordController,
      {required this.service})
      : super(LoginInitial());

  void changeLoadState() {
    isLoading = !isLoading;
    emit(LoginLoadingState(isLoading));
  }

  void postUserModel() async {
    if (formKey.currentState != null && formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      changeLoadState();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
      changeLoadState();
    }
  }
}

abstract class LoginState {}

class LoginInitial extends LoginState {}

class LoginLoadingState extends LoginState {
  final bool isLoading;

  LoginLoadingState(this.isLoading);
}
```

as you can see I want to watch isLoading then when its true i want to put a indicator on my button instead of text. But on button when i use it **like :**

```
context.watch<LoginCubit>().isLoading
                          ? CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive()
                          : Text("Login"),
```

Its giving that error i show with a photo. I dont know how to fix it i search from google and stackoverflow but cant found any solutions. Thanks for help guys!

Comment: Your problem is about accessing `cubit` from the same `context` that you have provided it from. It's closely related to this ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71219538/error-could-not-find-the-correct-providertimerstate-above-this-practice4homep/71220708#71220708 ) question (that I have also answered it) so take a look at it.

Comment: @AnteBule yes bro thats right! After provider I put BlocConsumer then its worked!